# Is there any efficient way to convert Z3's into assembly code?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, z3, smt, triton

I need something like that for x86 arch:

```
mov edi, dword ptr [0x7fc70000]
add edi, 0x11
sub edi, 0x33F0B753
```

After Z3 simplification I have got (memory 0x7FC70000 is symbolized):

```
bvadd (_ bv3423553726 32) MEM_0x7FC70000
```

The last step is converting Z3's AST into ASM code to get result like this:

```
mov edi, dword ptr [0x7fc70000]
add edi, 0xCC0F48BE
```

Is there any efficient way to perform last step? Should I parse SMT formula and convert it manually (bv -> mov...)?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [What is the best way to translate Z3's AST into ASM code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61801235), arguably it still is.  Or if not then it's pretty broad, I mean writing an optimizing compiler is not exactly something that fits in an SO answer.  You might consider transforming it to LLVM-IR to let LLVM's optimizing compiler do register allocation and so on to make whole functions out of statements like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to translate Z3's AST into ASM code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801235/what-is-the-best-way-to-translate-z3s-ast-into-asm-code)